# how to make height return a value not object

Tags: jquery

```js
window.addEventListener("updatedHeight", (event) => {
  let old = event.detail.height;
  alert(old);
  let newHeight = $(".chatbox_body")[0].scrollHeight;
  alert(newHeight);
  let height = $(".chatbox_body").scrollTop(newHeight - old);

  alert(height);

  window.livewire.emit("updateHeight", {
    height: height,
  });
  alert(height);
});
```

I've try to make the height to return a value but it return a object instead

Comment: Not sure what object are you getting, but try `alert(height.height);`

Comment: Don't use `alert(variable)` for debugging - you just get `[object Object]` - instead, use `console.log(variable)` - if you want text/other variables, then use comma, eg `console.log("height", variable)` then F12 and look in the console - you can expand the object to see which properties you *should* be using.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN docs](https://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/), `.scrollTop()` is used for getting value, and `.scrollTop(value)` is used for setting value without returning a value. So you can change:

```js
let height = $(".chatbox_body").scrollTop(newHeight - old);
```

to:

```js
$(".chatbox_body").scrollTop(newHeight - old);
let height = $(".chatbox_body").scrollTop();
```